# Как изменить дату на 1 день назад

Tags: java, дата

у меня есть переменная

```
String date = "10.11.2016";
```

как мне преобразовать ее в

```
String date = "09.11.2016";
```

Нужно чтобы это делалось для любой даты. Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала Вам нужно получить представление заданной даты в виде объекта класса, который предназначен для работы с датами. Этим классом является класс `Calendar`.

Получаете экземпляр класса `Calendar`:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Создаете объект, который преобразует дату в виде строки (определенного формата) в объект класса `Date`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Получаете объект класса `Date` из Вашей строки и инициализируете им `calendar`:

```
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
```

Изменяете объект `calendar` путем декремента даты:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

Получаете текстовое представление объект `calendar`:

```
date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: В который раз уже выручаете меня, маэстро. Спасибо!