# Как вычесть один день от даты

Tags: java

Как вычесть из даты один день правильно?
Пример: дата "2023-06-01"
Отнимаем один день от даты и должно правильно получиться "2023-05-31" или "2023-05-30" (в зависимости от максимального количества дней в месяце)

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+plusDays)

Comment: https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/12.3.php

Comment: `LocalDate.parse("2023-06-01").minusDays(1);`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить дату на 1 день назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592403/); [как работает .minusDays() в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882872/); [Как задать время в Java со смещением?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1486135/)

Answer (score 0):

```java
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2023, 06, 01);
System.out.println(date.minusDays(1));
```